# Type S Automotive underglow LEDS not responding to program in FastLEDS library

Tags: arduino-uno

hey y'all first post here so my apologies if I'm a bit of a NEWB, I'm currently trying to control a set of individually addressable 3-pin led strips I got from the  type S formula drift LED kit model number LM532654-1. Ive used FastLEDS for a few projects now but this one is stumping me. I may have the wrong type maybe or there could be a special line of code I need to enter to talk to the chip-sets. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also thank you all so much here on the forum, its saved my tail on so many occasions.
[image: The code Ive been playing with to figure it out. its not clean but it might give an idea what ive been working]
[image: This is the spec of the LED strips ive been working with, the SMD5050 front and back glow.]

```
//#include <WS2812Serial.h>
//#define USE_WS2812SERIAL
#define FASTLED_INTERNAL
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <FastLED_NeoPixel.h>
FASTLED_USING_NAMESPACE

#define DATA_PIN1           2
#define DATA_PIN2           3

#define COLOR_ORDER         GRB
//#define LED_TYPE            WS2812SERIAL
#define LED_TYPE            SM16703
#define NUM_LEDS_1 50
int i=NULL;


CRGB leds_1[NUM_LEDS_1];
FastLED_NeoPixel_Variant strip(leds_1, NUM_LEDS_1);


void setup(){
  //pinMode(DATA_PIN1,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN1,COLOR_ORDER>(leds_1, NUM_LEDS_1)
        .setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
        FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN2,COLOR_ORDER>(leds_1, NUM_LEDS_1)
        .setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );

}

void loop(){

  strip.begin(FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN1, GRB>(leds_1, NUM_LEDS_1));
  
  for(i=0; i<NUM_LEDS_1; i++){
    leds_1[i] = CRGB :: Green;
    FastLED.show();
    }

    for(i=0; i<NUM_LEDS_1; i++){
    leds_1[i] = CRGB :: Green;
    FastLED.show();
    }
```

Comment: No code as image please. Copy and paste the code as text into the question and format it correctly as code. Also please provide the link to that product page

Comment: probably not `individually addressable`

Comment: https://typesauto.com/products/type-s-formula-drift-pro-series-smart-led-exterior-lighting-kit-lm532654

Comment: Added the code in the description and posted the link above.

Comment: Ive gotten other Type S LEDS to function as Individually Addressable so as far as im aware these should function the same. But I am willing to test them out if you know of a way.

Comment: Now please format the code correctly. For that edit your question, select the code in the editor and them click the `{}` bitton.

Comment: How do you know that the LED-TYPE is correct? How do you even know, that the FastLED library can control them? The product page that you linked doesn't say anything about the used driver chips

Comment: I think that did it, I don't know the LED type, that's one of the things that I'm trying to figure out. The page I listed is unfortunately the only thing I have to go on. WS2812B worked for previous strips but ive mostly been shotgunning the different types that FastLEDS can support. Im currently searching the IC Chip smd5050 16703 amacrw1

Comment: https://viaisled.en.made-in-china.com/product/mjKxXShvlBVz/China-SMD5050-Addressable-Digital-16703-LED-Strip.html

the search leads me to some cheap chinese LEDS that run the same chip and those give some odd LED types Ws2811/Ucs1903/Sm16703

Comment: until you determine the exact model of the LEDs, this question is unrelated to the Arduino

Comment: Very well, Appreciate the help.

Comment: if i zoom in on the image of the strip showing the chip, it looks like it says xws28xx. Since you have the strip in-hand, search for the chip ids and that will tell you what led type you can feed fastled.

Comment: 16703 amacrw1 is the chip ID, but it really doesnt bring up much on google. The link is above to some cheap LEDS that run the same chip.